# Listview search with onClick showing wrong results

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I don't know if I am just having a brain fart or what, but I'm stumped. I have a listView populated by a string array that incorporates search functionality. When the user clicks a listView Item a dialog box appears with information related to that item. Everything works until I search, the search itself works and bring the correct result. Onclick switch case works without searching. The problem, when a search is entered whatever was searched for now assumes the number 0 spot in the array and shows the information for [0] array Item when the item that was searched for was further down the list. Say I have a array with string a,b,c. The onClick dialogs work by default but when I search for "b" and click on it it shows the information for "a" because b is now at the top of the list and "a" has disappeared.

```
<string-array name="letters">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
</string-array>
```

Built with

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources()
                    .getTextArray(R.array.letters));
```

Search function

```
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // DoNotCrush.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });
```

and the onClick

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                showDialog();
                //do stuff
                break;
            case 1:
                showDialog();
                //do stuff
                break;
            case 2:
                showDialog();
                //do stuff
                break;
}
        }
    });
```

I am assuming it is all in the switch statement and to not use the position variable, but I don't know what else t use since I don;t think you can assign id's to item in a string array. Any help would be appreciated just point me in the right direction.

Edit: Thanks to JARP I got my code working. I tossed the switch and used a if statement.

```
String a = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString(); <-JARP'S idea
if (a.equals("Some string")){
   //Do This
}else if(a.equals("Another string")){
   //Do This
}
```

This way seems like a lot of work as my listview has over 100 possibilities, but is the only way I could get it to work with the searchable edit text.

Comment: You need to get your item detail from the filtered data not the original one.

Comment: post `showDialog` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use adapter.getItem(position)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)

Comment: That wouldn't work if I type in "b" into the search the result will still give position "0" in which "b" would not be a match as position zero would have been "a";

Comment: Nvm, I was thinking about your answer wrong. Your answer did get me down the right path and got the code working.